# Give other controllers access to api call data

Tags: angularjs

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Make an api call as soon as the application runs (using `ui-router` and idea from http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/)
2. Store the data 'globally' so that my other controllers can have access to the data
3. Once the api call is done and all the controllers have resolved, show the UI (I don't want any flash of loaded content)

I know I could create an angular service to make those api calls within each controller, but if I have 2 controllers on the page, I don't want to make 2 of the same requests.

In the example below, I have a `nav.controller.js` that needs access to `myData`.

**home.config.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('home.client.view.html');
          },
          resolve: {
            myService: 'myApiService',
            myData: function(myApiService){
              return myService.get().$promise;
            }
          },
          controller: 'HomeCtrl as home'
        });
    }
  ]);
```

**home.controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['myData',
    function(myData){
      var self = this;

      // YAY WORKS!
      console.log(myData);
    }
  ]);
```

**nav.controller.js**

```
angular.module('myData')
  .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'myData',
    function($scope, myData) {
      // BOO DOESN'T WORK
      console.log(myData);
    }
  ]);
```

**another.controller.js**

```
angular.module('anotherModule')
  .controller('AnotherCtrl', ['$scope', 'myData',
    function($scope, myData) {
      // BOO DOESN'T WORK
      console.log(myData);
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: You need to make a service that not only does the api call, _but also_ stores the results (aka a cache).

Answer (score 0):

You should still use a service. However, this service shouldn't just make the API call - it should also store the data. Your code will look something like

**home.controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['myService',
    function(myService){
      var self = this;

      // YAY WORKS!
      console.log(myService.myData);
    }
  ]);
```

**nav.controller.js**

```
angular.module('myData')
  .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService',
    function($scope, myService) {
      // BOO DOESN'T WORK
      console.log(myService.myData);
    }
  ]);
```

**another.controller.js**

```
angular.module('anotherModule')
  .controller('AnotherCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService',
    function($scope, myService) {
      // BOO DOESN'T WORK
      console.log(myService.myData);
    }
  ]);
```

And inside your `myService.get()` function you store the returned data in `myData`